# How can I make textview.Contain search for word?

Tags: android

currently I am developing a basic AI that responds to user input.

I have this line of code:

`if (value.contains("hi")){
        test.setText("Hello.");
        speakOut();}
    }`

But this line is very easily triggered with words that are not "hi", such as this, which also contains "hi".

What code can I use to search for exact words rather than certain characters?

Comment: Why not use `equals()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then use the [`equals`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method :

```
"hi".equals(value)
```

If you have a sentence with the word hi, you could just split it :

```
String s = "Hi I'm this";
String [] words = s.split("\\s+"); //split by whitespaces

loop: for(String word : words){         
         if("hi".equals(word.toLowerCase())){
            System.out.println("hello");
            break loop;
         }
       }
```

Like the comments stated, you may have a sentence like "Hi, blablabla" and this won't work. But now that you have the idea you will be able to find a good regex that will catch only words.

Comment: equals wouldn't work because the user may also type "hi, my name is blablabla" and equals wouldn't answer to this.

Comment: Then do `value.startsWith("hi");`.

Comment: @Voicu And if you have the word "hibernate" in the sentence ? It will fail.

Comment: @Voicu Sure it will fail, but the OP is able to find a good regex to not catch all this characters. I'm just giving the idea.

Comment: Agreed. OP can also change `value.startsWith("hi");` to `value.startsWith("hi ");` or `value.startsWith("hi,");` or etc. and have it work.

Comment: I thought about adding spaces but then I wouldn't get a response for "Hi" only.

Comment: you can use a regex for this purpose. use pattern matching with regex

Comment: Basically I need to create a loop that will search for a word rather than characters. I am trying to do that right now.

Comment: @user2471760 What I did doesn't help ? What problem are you facing ?

Comment: Actually it probably helps but I am still a java beginner so I am trying to understand loops. I was just reading a loop lesson to get a better understanding of what you just wrote. What does .split actually do?

Comment: Ok , basically you have a sentence like "Hi this is me". The method splits the String in multipart. An array is created an each slot of the array contains a word (so in this case there are 4 slots). Then I just loop through all the slots and check if one contains the words "hi".

Comment: that is actually very helpful and exactly what I need, but what I need to understand now is what the \\s+ is for. I believe that probably uses the space as a filter to split the string?

Comment: the \\s+ tells that the sentence has to be split when a whitespace is detected. So "Hi this is me" becames "Hi" "this" "is" "me"

Comment: alright, thanks for the great help so far. where can I get a list of the codes like \\s+, \n etc?

Comment: @user2471760 if you input is say hi you need to search for the word hi right?

Comment: @user2471760 Here's a tutorial. http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html